# Easting northing to latitude longitude

Tags: gps, bing-maps

I've got coordinates of location in easting/northing format but I need to convert it to proper lat long to center it in bing maps. Any formula or details how to convert easting/northing to lat/lon?

EDIT: To be more specific, I need to convert SVY21 coordinates to the to WGS84

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Eastings and northings are distances east and north, respectively, of a base point. The base point is usually a latitude and longitude, and eastings and northings are normally expressed in meters or feet. The easting and northing, however, is usually offset a particular value to make them positive and allow them to express places west and south of the base point.

In general, converting from one coordinate system to another is not simple, since both may have different ellipsoids (Earth models) and datums. As I understand, the formulas for converting from one coordinate system to another are rather complex.

SVY21, however, uses the exact same datum and ellipsoid as WGS84, making the task simpler. In SVY21, the base point for eastings and northings is Base 7 at Pierce Reservoir.  According to the [geodetic version of SVY21](https://epsg.org/datum_6757/SVY21.html), this base point is 1 deg. 22 min. 02.9154 sec. North and 103 deg. 49 min 31.9752 sec. East (that is, a latitude of about 1.3674765 degrees and a longitude of about 103.8255487 degrees; the [well known text](https://epsg.org/crs/wkt/id/3414) for the *projected version*, however, uses a slightly different latitude and longitude). The offset for the easting is 28001.642 meters, and the offset for the northing is 38744.572 meters. The EPSG code is 3414. I will assume your eastings and northings are expressed in meters.

Since SVY21 uses the same system as WGS84, all you have to do is:

- Subtract the easting and northing by their respective offset values. (The values will be in meters.)
- Find the longitude of the given point by finding the destination point given the base point, the absolute value of the easting, and the bearing of 90 degrees if the easting is positive, or 270 degrees if it's negative. This calculation is called solving the "direct geodesic problem", and this is discussed in C.F.F. Karney's article "[Algorithms for geodesics](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00190-012-0578-z), 2012.
- Find the latitude of the given point by finding the destination point given the base point, the absolute value of the northing, and the bearing of 0 degrees if the northing is positive, or 180 degrees if it's negative.

Comment: are you referring to Haversine's formula? How about from easting/northing to lat/lon?

Comment: No, I'm referring to the spherical law of cosines, though it may also work with Vincenty's direct formula.

Answer (score 4):

There are hundreds of different coordinate systems - Easting/Northing and Lat/Long are *types* of coordinates, but they're not enough to uniquely identify the system from which those coordinates are obtained.

You need to either have an EPSG code (e.g. 4326, 4269, 27700, 32701) or, alternatively, the details of the spatial reference system (the datum, projection, prime meridian and unit of measure) for both your source and chosen destination format. 
You mention "GPS" in your question title, so I'm assuming that the lat/lon you require is defined relative to the WGS84 datum used by global positioning systems, but there are still many projections of that datum that could lead to different Easting/Northing values.

Once you've got the details of the projection used, you can perform the transformation in code using something like the Proj.4 library (http://trac.osgeo.org/proj/)

Comment: the results I'm getting are in SVY21 format and I'll need to convert it to WGS84 and plot it in bing maps. Is that possible using the library?

Answer (score 4):

I've converted a Javascript implementation into T-SQL functions for the WGS84 to Latitude/Longitude values.  Feel free to use as you see fit.  If you need a different coordinate system, check out the University of Wisconsin - Green Bay web page that I used as a source and get the updated constants.

```
    drop function UF_utm_to_lat
go
create function UF_utm_to_lat(@utmz float, @x float, @y float) returns float
as
begin
    --Based on code from this page: http://www.uwgb.edu/dutchs/usefuldata/ConvertUTMNoOZ.HTM
    declare @latitude float;
    declare @longitude float;
    set @latitude = 0.00;
    set @longitude = 0.00;

    --Declarations
    declare @a float;
    declare @f float;
    declare @drad float;
    declare @k0 float;
    declare @b float;
    declare @e float;
    declare @e0 float;
    declare @esq float;
    declare @e0sq float;
    declare @zcm float;
    declare @e1 float;
    declare @M float;
    declare @mu float;
    declare @phi1 float;
    declare @C1 float;
    declare @T1 float;
    declare @N1 float;
    declare @R1 float;
    declare @D float;
    declare @phi float;
    declare @lng float;
    declare @lngd float;

    --Datum Info here: Name, a, b, f, 1/f
    --WGS 84    6,378,137.0 6356752.314 0.003352811 298.2572236

    set @a = 6378137.0;
    set @b = 6356752.314;
    set @f = 0.003352811;
    set @drad = PI()/180.0;
    set @k0 = 0.9996; --scale on central meridian

    set @e = SQRT(1.0 - (@b/@a)*(@b/@a)); --Eccentricity
    --e = Math.sqrt(1 - (b/a)*(b/a));//eccentricity
    set @e0 = @e/SQRT(1.0 - @e*@e); --Called e prime in reference
    --e0 = e/Math.sqrt(1 - e*e);//Called e prime in reference
    set @esq = (1.0 - (@b/@a)*(@b/@a)); --e squared for use in expansions
    --esq = (1 - (b/a)*(b/a));//e squared for use in expansions
    set @e0sq = @e*@e/(1.0-@e*@e); --e0 squared - always even powers
    --e0sq = e*e/(1-e*e);// e0 squared - always even powers
    set @zcm = 3.0 + 6.0*(@utmz-1.0) - 180.0; --Central meridian of zone
    --zcm = 3 + 6*(utmz-1) - 180;//Central meridian of zone
    set @e1 = (1.0 - SQRT(1.0 - @e*@e))/(1.0 + SQRT(1.0 - @e*@e)); --Called e1 in USGS PP 1395 also
    --e1 = (1 - Math.sqrt(1 - e*e))/(1 + Math.sqrt(1 - e*e));//Called e1 in USGS PP 1395 also
    set @M = 0.0 + @y / @k0; --Arc length along standard meridian
    --M = M0 + y/k0;//Arc length along standard meridian. 
    set @mu = @M/(@a*(1.0 - @esq*(1.0/4.0 + @esq*(3.0/64.0 + 5.0*@esq/256.0))));
    --mu = M/(a*(1 - esq*(1/4 + esq*(3/64 + 5*esq/256))));
    set @phi1 = @mu + @e1*(3.0/2.0 - 27.0*@e1*@e1/32.0)*SIN(2.0*@mu) + @e1*@e1*(21.0/16.0 - 55.0*@e1*@e1/32.0)*SIN(4.0*@mu); --Footprint Latitude
    --phi1 = mu + e1*(3/2 - 27*e1*e1/32)*Math.sin(2*mu) + e1*e1*(21/16 -55*e1*e1/32)*Math.sin(4*mu);//Footprint Latitude
    set @phi1 = @phi1 + @e1*@e1*@e1*(SIN(6.0*@mu)*151.0/96.0 + @e1*SIN(8.0*@mu)*1097.0/512.0);
    --phi1 = phi1 + e1*e1*e1*(Math.sin(6*mu)*151/96 + e1*Math.sin(8*mu)*1097/512);
    set @C1 = @e0sq*POWER(COS(@phi1),2.0);
    --C1 = e0sq*Math.pow(Math.cos(phi1),2);
    set @T1 = POWER(TAN(@phi1),2.0);
    --T1 = Math.pow(Math.tan(phi1),2);
    set @N1 = @a/SQRT(1.0-POWER(@e*SIN(@phi1),2.0));
    --N1 = a/Math.sqrt(1-Math.pow(e*Math.sin(phi1),2));
    set @R1 = @N1*(1.0-@e*@e)/(1.0-POWER(@e*SIN(@phi1),2.0));
    --R1 = N1*(1-e*e)/(1-Math.pow(e*Math.sin(phi1),2));
    set @D = (@x-500000.0)/(@N1*@k0);
    --D = (x-500000)/(N1*k0);
    set @phi = (@D*@D)*(1.0/2.0 - @D*@D*(5.0 + 3.0*@T1 + 10.0*@C1 - 4.0*@C1*@C1 - 9.0*@e0sq)/24.0);
    --phi = (D*D)*(1/2 - D*D*(5 + 3*T1 + 10*C1 - 4*C1*C1 - 9*e0sq)/24);
    set @phi = @phi + POWER(@D,6.0)*(61.0 + 90.0*@T1 + 298.0*@C1 + 45.0*@T1*@T1 - 252.0*@e0sq - 3.0*@C1*@C1)/720.0;
    --phi = phi + Math.pow(D,6)*(61 + 90*T1 + 298*C1 + 45*T1*T1 -252*e0sq - 3*C1*C1)/720;
    set @phi = @phi1 - (@N1*TAN(@phi1)/@R1)*@phi;
    --phi = phi1 - (N1*Math.tan(phi1)/R1)*phi;


    set @latitude = FLOOR(1000000.0*@phi/@drad)/1000000.0;

    set @lng = @D*(1.0 + @D*@D*((-1.0 - 2.0*@T1 - @C1)/6.0 + @D*@D*(5.0 - 2.0*@C1 + 28.0*@T1 - 3.0*@C1*@C1 + 8.0*@e0sq + 24.0*@T1*@T1)/120))/COS(@phi1);
    set @lngd = @zcm+@lng/@drad;
    set @longitude = FLOOR(1000000.0*@lngd)/1000000.0;


    return @latitude;
end
go
drop function UF_utm_to_long
go
create function UF_utm_to_long(@utmz float, @x float, @y float) returns float
as
begin
    --Based on code from this page: http://www.uwgb.edu/dutchs/usefuldata/ConvertUTMNoOZ.HTM
    declare @latitude float;
    declare @longitude float;
    set @latitude = 0.00;
    set @longitude = 0.00;

    --Declarations
    declare @a float;
    declare @f float;
    declare @drad float;
    declare @k0 float;
    declare @b float;
    declare @e float;
    declare @e0 float;
    declare @esq float;
    declare @e0sq float;
    declare @zcm float;
    declare @e1 float;
    declare @M float;
    declare @mu float;
    declare @phi1 float;
    declare @C1 float;
    declare @T1 float;
    declare @N1 float;
    declare @R1 float;
    declare @D float;
    declare @phi float;
    declare @lng float;
    declare @lngd float;

    --Datum Info here: Name, a, b, f, 1/f
    --WGS 84    6,378,137.0 6356752.314 0.003352811 298.2572236

    set @a = 6378137.0;
    set @b = 6356752.314;
    set @f = 0.003352811;
    set @drad = PI()/180.0;
    set @k0 = 0.9996; --scale on central meridian

    set @e = SQRT(1.0 - (@b/@a)*(@b/@a)); --Eccentricity
    --e = Math.sqrt(1 - (b/a)*(b/a));//eccentricity
    set @e0 = @e/SQRT(1.0 - @e*@e); --Called e prime in reference
    --e0 = e/Math.sqrt(1 - e*e);//Called e prime in reference
    set @esq = (1.0 - (@b/@a)*(@b/@a)); --e squared for use in expansions
    --esq = (1 - (b/a)*(b/a));//e squared for use in expansions
    set @e0sq = @e*@e/(1.0-@e*@e); --e0 squared - always even powers
    --e0sq = e*e/(1-e*e);// e0 squared - always even powers
    set @zcm = 3.0 + 6.0*(@utmz-1.0) - 180.0; --Central meridian of zone
    --zcm = 3 + 6*(utmz-1) - 180;//Central meridian of zone
    set @e1 = (1.0 - SQRT(1.0 - @e*@e))/(1.0 + SQRT(1.0 - @e*@e)); --Called e1 in USGS PP 1395 also
    --e1 = (1 - Math.sqrt(1 - e*e))/(1 + Math.sqrt(1 - e*e));//Called e1 in USGS PP 1395 also
    set @M = 0.0 + @y / @k0; --Arc length along standard meridian
    --M = M0 + y/k0;//Arc length along standard meridian. 
    set @mu = @M/(@a*(1.0 - @esq*(1.0/4.0 + @esq*(3.0/64.0 + 5.0*@esq/256.0))));
    --mu = M/(a*(1 - esq*(1/4 + esq*(3/64 + 5*esq/256))));
    set @phi1 = @mu + @e1*(3.0/2.0 - 27.0*@e1*@e1/32.0)*SIN(2.0*@mu) + @e1*@e1*(21.0/16.0 - 55.0*@e1*@e1/32.0)*SIN(4.0*@mu); --Footprint Latitude
    --phi1 = mu + e1*(3/2 - 27*e1*e1/32)*Math.sin(2*mu) + e1*e1*(21/16 -55*e1*e1/32)*Math.sin(4*mu);//Footprint Latitude
    set @phi1 = @phi1 + @e1*@e1*@e1*(SIN(6.0*@mu)*151.0/96.0 + @e1*SIN(8.0*@mu)*1097.0/512.0);
    --phi1 = phi1 + e1*e1*e1*(Math.sin(6*mu)*151/96 + e1*Math.sin(8*mu)*1097/512);
    set @C1 = @e0sq*POWER(COS(@phi1),2.0);
    --C1 = e0sq*Math.pow(Math.cos(phi1),2);
    set @T1 = POWER(TAN(@phi1),2.0);
    --T1 = Math.pow(Math.tan(phi1),2);
    set @N1 = @a/SQRT(1.0-POWER(@e*SIN(@phi1),2.0));
    --N1 = a/Math.sqrt(1-Math.pow(e*Math.sin(phi1),2));
    set @R1 = @N1*(1.0-@e*@e)/(1.0-POWER(@e*SIN(@phi1),2.0));
    --R1 = N1*(1-e*e)/(1-Math.pow(e*Math.sin(phi1),2));
    set @D = (@x-500000.0)/(@N1*@k0);
    --D = (x-500000)/(N1*k0);
    set @phi = (@D*@D)*(1.0/2.0 - @D*@D*(5.0 + 3.0*@T1 + 10.0*@C1 - 4.0*@C1*@C1 - 9.0*@e0sq)/24.0);
    --phi = (D*D)*(1/2 - D*D*(5 + 3*T1 + 10*C1 - 4*C1*C1 - 9*e0sq)/24);
    set @phi = @phi + POWER(@D,6.0)*(61.0 + 90.0*@T1 + 298.0*@C1 + 45.0*@T1*@T1 - 252.0*@e0sq - 3.0*@C1*@C1)/720.0;
    --phi = phi + Math.pow(D,6)*(61 + 90*T1 + 298*C1 + 45*T1*T1 -252*e0sq - 3*C1*C1)/720;
    set @phi = @phi1 - (@N1*TAN(@phi1)/@R1)*@phi;
    --phi = phi1 - (N1*Math.tan(phi1)/R1)*phi;

    set @latitude = FLOOR(1000000.0*@phi/@drad)/1000000.0;

    set @lng = @D*(1.0 + @D*@D*((-1.0 - 2.0*@T1 - @C1)/6.0 + @D*@D*(5.0 - 2.0*@C1 + 28.0*@T1 - 3.0*@C1*@C1 + 8.0*@e0sq + 24.0*@T1*@T1)/120))/COS(@phi1);
    set @lngd = @zcm+@lng/@drad;
    set @longitude = FLOOR(1000000.0*@lngd)/1000000.0;


    return @longitude;
end
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a relatively simple solution in perl:

> So, first of all, make sure you have Perl installed. Then, install the
>   following four modules:
>
> Geo::HelmertTransform Geography::NationalGrid CAM::DBF
>   mySociety::GeoUtil
>
> You can do this in a number of ways. Here's how I did it:

```
# Geo::HelmertTransform 
wget http://search.cpan.org/CPAN/authors/id/M/MY/MYSOCIETY/Geo-HelmertTransform-1.13.tar.gz 
tar xzf Geo-HelmertTransform-1.13.tar.gz  
perl Makefile.PL 
make 
make install

# Geography::NationalGrid 
http://search.cpan.org/CPAN/authors/id/P/PK/PKENT/Geography-NationalGrid-1.6.tar.gz 
tar xzf Geography-NationalGrid-1.6.tar.gz 
perl Makefile.PL 
make 
make install

# CAM::DBF 
wget http://search.cpan.org/CPAN/authors/id/C/CL/CLOTHO/CAM-DBF-1.02.tgz 
tar xzf CAM-DBF-1.02.tgz 
perl Makefile.PL 
make 
make install

# mySociety::GeoUtil
# See: http://parlvid.mysociety.org:81/os/ -> https://github.com/mysociety/commonlib/blob/master/perllib/mySociety/GeoUtil.pm
mkdir -p mySociety 
wget -O mySociety/GeoUtil.pm 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mysociety/commonlib/master/perllib/mySociety/GeoUtil.pm'
```

> 1. Get GB data.
>
> Download the Great Britain "Code-Point® Open" dataset by clicking here
>   and following the instructions. Once you've downloaded codepo_gb.zip
>   you can extract it as follows:
>
> unzip codepo_gb.zip
>
> Presuming that the unzipped files are now in the current directory,
>   you can then run the following perlscript in order to parse the data,
>   extract the GB eastings/northings and convert them to
>   latitude/longitude.

```
use strict;
use mySociety::GeoUtil qw/national_grid_to_wgs84/;

while (<>) {
    my @x=split(/,/); # split csv
    my ($pc, $east, $north) = ($x[0], $x[10], $x[11]);
    $pc=~s/\"//g; # remove quotes around postcode
    my ($lat, $lng) = national_grid_to_wgs84($east, $north, "G"); # "G" means Great Britain
    print "$pc,$lat,$lng\n";
}
```

(To call, save the last code block to a .pl file, and then call `perl script.pl your.csv` ... also remember, $x[0], $x[10] and $x[11] should be the column numbers of postcode, easting and northing respectively.

Full credit to http://baroque.posterous.com/uk-postcode-latitudelongitude

Comment: would be good but I prefer the computations and/or formulas for the conversion for portability. secondly, svy21 is singapore's so UK's SVY to WGS84 conversion aren't applicable.

Comment: My bad, hopefully it can help someone though as I stumbled upon this question while in a rush to find a solution and this was the easiest method for British conversion.

Comment: true. that's why i didn't downvote it since someone might find this useful too.

Comment: This worked beautifully for me with some UK bus stop locations as easting/northing that I needed to convert to WGS84.  Pity I can only upvote by 1 - you saved me the effort of porting the JavaScript algorithm I'd found into Perl!!

Answer (score 0):

```js
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION toLatLong(E STRING, N STRING)
RETURNS STRING--[Latitude,Longitude]
LANGUAGE js
AS r"""
var __left0__ = [6377563.396, 6356256.909]
    var a = __left0__ [0];
    var b = __left0__ [1];
    var F0 = 0.9996012717;
    var lat0 = (49 * Math.PI) / 180;
    var lon0 = (-(2) * Math.PI) / 180;
    var __left0__ = [-(100000), 400000]
    var N0 = __left0__ [0];
    var E0 = __left0__ [1];
    var e2 = 1 - (b * b) / (a * a);
    var n = (a - b) / (a + b);
    var __left0__ = [lat0, 0]
    var lat = __left0__ [0];
    var M = __left0__ [1];
    while ((N - N0) - M >= 1e-05) {
        var lat = ((N - N0) - M) / (a * F0) + lat;
        var M1 = (((1 + n) + (5.0 / 4) * Math.pow (n, 2)) + (5.0 / 4) * Math.pow (n, 3)) * (lat - lat0);
        var M2 = (((3 * n + 3 * Math.pow (n, 2)) + (21.0 / 8) * Math.pow (n, 3)) * Math.sin (lat - lat0)) * Math.cos (lat + lat0);
        var M3 = (((15.0 / 8) * Math.pow (n, 2) + (15.0 / 8) * Math.pow (n, 3)) * Math.sin (2 * (lat - lat0))) * Math.cos (2 * (lat + lat0));
        var M4 = (((35.0 / 24) * Math.pow (n, 3)) * Math.sin (3 * (lat - lat0))) * Math.cos (3 * (lat + lat0));
        var M = (b * F0) * (((M1 - M2) + M3) - M4);
    }
    var nu = (a * F0) / Math.sqrt (1 - e2 * Math.pow (Math.sin (lat), 2));
    var rho = ((a * F0) * (1 - e2)) * Math.pow (1 - e2 * Math.pow (Math.sin (lat), 2), -(1.5));
    var eta2 = nu / rho - 1;
    var secLat = 1.0 / Math.cos (lat);
    var VII = Math.tan (lat) / ((2 * rho) * nu);
    var VIII = (Math.tan (lat) / ((24 * rho) * Math.pow (nu, 3))) * (((5 + 3 * Math.pow (Math.tan (lat), 2)) + eta2) - (9 * Math.pow (Math.tan (lat), 2)) * eta2);
    var IX = (Math.tan (lat) / ((720 * rho) * Math.pow (nu, 5))) * ((61 + 90 * Math.pow (Math.tan (lat), 2)) + 45 * Math.pow (Math.tan (lat), 4));
    var X = secLat / nu;
    var XI = (secLat / (6 * Math.pow (nu, 3))) * (nu / rho + 2 * Math.pow (Math.tan (lat), 2));
    var XII = (secLat / (120 * Math.pow (nu, 5))) * ((5 + 28 * Math.pow (Math.tan (lat), 2)) + 24 * Math.pow (Math.tan (lat), 4));
    var XIIA = (secLat / (5040 * Math.pow (nu, 7))) * (((61 + 662 * Math.pow (Math.tan (lat), 2)) + 1320 * Math.pow (Math.tan (lat), 4)) + 720 * Math.pow (Math.tan (lat), 6));
    var dE = E - E0;

    var lat_1 = ((lat - VII * Math.pow (dE, 2)) + VIII * Math.pow (dE, 4)) - IX * Math.pow (dE, 6);
    //print (lat_1);

    var lon_1 = (((lon0 + X * dE) - XI * Math.pow (dE, 3)) + XII * Math.pow (dE, 5)) - XIIA * Math.pow (dE, 7);
    
    var H = 0;
    var x_1 = ((nu / F0 + H) * Math.cos (lat_1)) * Math.cos (lon_1);
    var y_1 = ((nu / F0 + H) * Math.cos (lat_1)) * Math.sin (lon_1);
    var z_1 = (((1 - e2) * nu) / F0 + H) * Math.sin (lat_1);
    var s = -(20.4894) * Math.pow (10, -(6));
    var __left0__ = [446.448, -(125.157), +(542.06)];
    var tx = __left0__ [0];
    var ty = __left0__ [1];
    var tz = __left0__ [2];
    var __left0__ = [0.1502, 0.247, 0.8421];
    var rxs = __left0__ [0];
    var rys = __left0__ [1];
    var rzs = __left0__ [2];
    var __left0__ = [(rxs * Math.PI) / (180 * 3600.0), (rys * Math.PI) / (180 * 3600.0), (rzs * Math.PI) / (180 * 3600.0)];
    var rx = __left0__ [0];
    var ry = __left0__ [1];
    var rz = __left0__ [2];
    var x_2 = ((tx + (1 + s) * x_1) + -(rz) * y_1) + ry * z_1;
    var y_2 = ((ty + rz * x_1) + (1 + s) * y_1) + -(rx) * z_1;
    var z_2 = ((tz + -(ry) * x_1) + rx * y_1) + (1 + s) * z_1;
    var __left0__ = [6378137.0, 6356752.3141]
    var a_2 = __left0__ [0];
    var b_2 = __left0__ [1];
    var e2_2 = 1 - (b_2 * b_2) / (a_2 * a_2);
    var p = Math.sqrt (Math.pow (x_2, 2) + Math.pow (y_2, 2));
    var lat = Math.atan2 (z_2, p * (1 - e2_2));
    //print ('Lat before iteration', lat);
    var latold = 2 * Math.PI;
    while (Math.abs (lat - latold) > Math.pow (10, -(16))) {
        var __left0__ = [latold, lat]
        var lat = __left0__ [0];
        var latold = __left0__ [1];
        var nu_2 = a_2 / Math.sqrt (1 - e2_2 * Math.pow (Math.sin (latold), 2));
        var lat = Math.atan2 (z_2 + (e2_2 * nu_2) * Math.sin (latold), p);
    }
    var lon = Math.atan2 (y_2, x_2);
    var H = p / Math.cos (lat) - nu_2;
    var lat = (lat * 180) / Math.PI;
    var lon = (lon * 180) / Math.PI;
    return [lat, lon]
""";

WITH
  test AS (

  SELECT

    '532718' AS easting,

    '181075' AS northing,

  UNION ALL

  SELECT

    '532718',

    '181075' )

SELECT 
split(toLatLong(Easting,Northing),",")[0] as latitude,  
split(toLatLong(Easting,Northing),",")[1] as longitude 
FROM  test
```

pls run this on bigquery

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).