# Convert WGS84 into Latitude and Longitude

Tags: iphone, location, android-mapview, cllocation

I need to convert wgs84 values into latitude and longitude values. I need to convert values into latitude and longitude and drop a pin on mapview. For example in plist i have got values    SDO_X1= 39616.4535 and SDO_Y1=37472.9078, How do i convert these values into degree,radians or latitude and longitude, please help me. All locations are for Singapore

Comment: WGS-84 _are_ latitude and longitude.

Answer (score 1):

Re "values SDO_X1= 39616.4535 and SDO_Y1=37472.9078".

Knowing that these are based on "WGS-84" is not enough information to answer the question. They are not "WGS84 values", because "WGS84 values", in decimal form, would be degrees decimal, e.g. -180 to +180 in X, -90 to +90 in Y.

Judging by the size of the values, they are probably measurements in meters, relative to some reference point.

Googling, I see that the official projection for Singapore is known as "SVY21".

CAVEAT: Unless these are from a land survey prior to 2004, in which case you need to ask a local land surveyor or appropriate government official to help you convert these. Or any reference source that provides the table or formula for these older surveys.

Assuming these are SVY21 values, then see the answer to [Easting northing to latitude longitude](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7872539/easting-northing-to-latitude-longitude)