# How convert wgs 84 to lat/long in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, gis, wgs84

I having a little trouble figuring out how to convert between types of coordinates. I have a list of coordinate sets with the following description. I have been searching around and did find some code to do this, but it does not SQL Query.

"Coordinates are always in the WGS84 system. All coordinates a represented as Decimal values x and y.

**An example:**

```
Ellipsoid:
    wgs84 (world geodetic system 1984)

UTM Zone:
    39 - 48E to 54E

UTM Projection:
    X, m: 702964.0000     ------->   latitude : 27.7818550282488
    Y, m: 3074740.0000    ------->   longitude : 53.0598812425032
```

> The query should be SQL Server Query.

Well, I need to convert these to long/lat
Anyone who can provide some code for doing this?

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=40f08beb0cce23b7896d7370950fdedb) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: You need to do a bit of math https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Transverse_Mercator_coordinate_system

Comment: It tends to be more than a bit and is tricky to get right. Any chance you can defer on performing the conversion until you get the values into HLL? Then you can use some sort of existing software library function to do it so you don't have to write all the tricky code in MSSQL.

Answer (score 1):

You can probably use the `UF_utm_to_lat()` function from this previous answer.

[Easting northing to latitude longitude](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7872539/easting-northing-to-latitude-longitude)

Comment: I think your answer is not working see this:
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=d65cb638efcf4cb68ed178e78c116373

Comment: Yup. Your xy is projected already. I have to lookup what they match up to.

Comment: see this example: http://www.sql-server-helper.com/sql-server-2008/convert-latitude-longitude-to-geography-point.aspx
i loaded it in fiddle: 
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=6b2340a2f1f36c83a2f1441bbf06cb44
just missing a conversion from your projection to a earth point. reading up on it.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't found suitable t-sql code for this, so I have finally developed a library in .NET to be called from transact sql 
Converts WGS84/UTM coordinates to Latitude and Longitude

You can download it from github:

https://github.com/j-v-garcia/UTM2LATITUDE

```
   usage:

SELECT dbo.UTM2LATITUDE(723399.51,4373328.5,'S',30) AS Latitude, dbo.UTM2LONGITUDE(723399.51,4373328.5,'S',30) AS Longitude

    result: 

    39,4805657453054    -0,402592727245112

    <param name="XUTM">pos UTM X</param>
    <param name="YUTM">pos UTM Y</param>
    <param name="LatBand">Latitude band grid zone designation letter (see http://www.dmap.co.uk/utmworld.htm) </param>
    <param name="LongBand">Longitude band grid zone designation number (see http://www.dmap.co.uk/utmworld.htm) </param>
```

Answer (score 1):

This T-SQL was adapted from some JavaScript code supplied by Xander Bakker at ESRI (replace `[column_name]` with your own geography shape field).

```
180.0 / PI() * (2.0 * ATAN(EXP(([column_name].Shape.STY / (2.0 * PI() * 6378137.0 / 2.0) * 180.0) * PI() / 180.0)) - PI() / 2.0) as Latitude, -- Convert Y to Latitude

([column_name].Shape.STX / (2.0 * PI() * 6378137.0 / 2.0) * 180.0)  as Longitude, -- Convert X to Longitude
```

I spot checked numerous locations and they were all spot on.