# Convert easting and northing value into longitude and latitude in bigquery

Tags: python, sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

Convert easting and northing value into longitude and latitude in BST (British standard timezone) bigquery ?

Can anyone help to find solutions in bigquery.i have tried checking multiple way but i didn't get the direct solution on this.i don't how to resolve this.i tried in bigquery geography function

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7872539/easting-northing-to-latitude-longitude ?

Comment: Do you mean British National Grid (OSGB)? BST is time zone, not a coordinate system.

Comment: check if this UDF solution works for you - https://mentin.medium.com/st-transform-in-bigquery-project-any-coordinates-to-lng-lat-and-back-84957a39252a